# Attending a conference before or after resigning?

Tags: professionalism, professional-development

A local DC-based university invited me earlier this year to attend a conference they are putting on for professionals in my industry (healthcare). I am looking forward to attending, but I am also putting in my resignation sometime within the next couple of weeks (with a long lead time). The opportunity is being funded by a department of the university and will not cost my company anything. To me, it seems like I should be able to attend without issue, regardless of whether I am leaving or not. However, I could see my supervisor and leadership getting bent out of shape about it (which probably speaks to the org culture). I originally planned on saying something before the conference, but it also crossed my mind to wait until afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no cost to your company, I don't see any difference between attending when:

1. You had not submitted your resignation (you are not leaving).
2. The conference occurs during your resignation period.
3. The conference occurs after you had already left.

There are however two points, I would bring up with the company:

- Does the company want you to take vacation time to cover the time you are off work (assuming your attendance is during your normal work time/days)?
- Does the company want you to represent them in some way (say that you work there, list open positions, etc ...)? They may also say the opposite (not to mention them).

Comment: I imagine that after they find out about my resignation, they will want me to use vacation time vs. my general hours, though I still plan on representing the organization at this point. I am giving them a very long lead time (months), and I personally don't see an issue representing them while I am still there (I've represented other orgs during other long resignation periods). Unfortunately, no one else can go in my stead, and the invite was specific to me (both in my role with the company and my work in the field). I hope that they will still want me to represent them but perhaps they won't.

Comment: If they require me to use my vacation time, then I would go as an independent professional.

Answer (score 1):

So long as:

1: There is *definitely* no cost to your company and
2: You aren't going as a representative of your company (but instead as a private citizen) and
3: You being there isn't taking up a space that would otherwise be offered to someone else at the company.

Then it is fine to go and if Management raises a stink about it, to politely remind them to get thee hence.

However, if any of those are true, then courtesy would dictate that you attend as yourself, without any affiliation with your company.

Comment: I would add that cost to company includes OP going on work time as opposed to PTO.  They would have let OP attend on work time because of some perceived future value, that doesn't exist if OP leaves.

Comment: It will not cost them anything, but I don't personally see a reason why I couldn't go to represent the company despite preparing to leave. I've held other positions where I continued making site visits and representing the company to outside stakeholders up to my last day, and I've always continued to represent any org I've represented in very positive ways during my resignation period. In this case, my company will have months of lead time in which I will still be acting on their behalf in a variety of capacities.